# How can I display current alias value in Windows shell?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, cmd.exe

I want to know what is the value of the alias `python` in my current windows shell. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell, use:

```
(Get-Command python).Source
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the value of the alias, one can type :

```
where python
```

Comment: in cmd yes, in powershell no

Answer (score 0):

It could also be rerouted under registry

LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options

Another way of looking is to use the assoc

```
assoc .py   -> returns eg Python
ftype Python
```